# Windows Mobile C# DataSet Update on Background Thread

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mobile, dataset

I would like to update a System.Data.DataTable in a background thread:

```
m_MyThread = new Thread(UpdateIt) { 
                 isBackground = true, 
                 Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal };

public void UpdateIt()
{
    var adapter = new DataSetAdapter();
    adapter.Fill(MyDataTable);
    adapter.Dispose();

    m_MyThread = null;
}
```

However, there is a problem.  There is a UserControl (view) open within a stack of UserControls which contains a control (like a list box) that is bound to a DataView on data table (MyOtherDataTable.DefaultView) within this DataSet (not even bound to the MyDataTable I am trying to fill).

As a result, mscore.dll dies a horrible death when attempting to create/BringToFront another control.  It throws a cedevice.log and kdmp file (Which I have tried to analyze with Watson).

I am wondering if there is a way around this.  I have even attempted to do this operation in a Form.Timer()...but the result is the same.

When the "Fill" is performed within the foreground thread, everything works perfoectly.

Thanks in advance for any insight....